# Close browser tab nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs server created with express.
So for example i have this url "localhost:3000/success" that it's called after a login success.
Is it possible that this url closes the browser tab in which is invoked? how?
I haven't got the possibility to use the client side (only server side).
Thank you!

Comment: You want the server to run some code, which will close a browser tab on the client side, *without client side code*? Do you understand what you are asking for, because if you did, you'd know that it is impossible.

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I wanted to know if there was other possibilities. But ok, this is very good! I'm not expert in nodejs/javascript. :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why don't you have a possibility to use the client code?

What you need to do is to make `/success` URL serve a very simple HTML page that includes a script which will close the window / tab for you:

```
<script>
    window.close();
</script>
```

Comment: @user2549764 even though this is working as expected it is one of the most user unfriendly things i can think of. Why would one use this approach?

Comment: @aaki: One thing I can think of: Closing a Facebook login popup window after positive authentication?

Comment: @webkit, Oh, it is supported, but differently. In Firefox (67), Chrome (73) and Opera (58), you can only `window.close()` windows that were opened by another script (not by user) - you can try that by running the command in console. Edge (44, EdgeHTML 18) will show you a popup requesting confirmation, but not sure for how long, as they're moving to Chrome too.

Comment: @npe true, sorry I meant not supported as is, will work as you said if window was named and opened by script

Comment: Very Smart Solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to close browser tabs on the client's webbrowser with only server-side code.

Comment: Ok! I have and idea... if i load a javascript script when i load the "localhost:3000/success" url? Maybe is it possible to close the browser tab? and how? can you help me?

Comment: @user2549764 that is called "client side" code, and it is as simple as calling one single javascript function: `window.close()`